# Getting 403 forbidden when dynamically loading images in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am loading json data from my api that contains urls to images outside of my domain. I've done this in the past, not with Angular, and I've never seen this problem...

In my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/PZJKZ/) when I click 'Search' two images appear but they are both throwing a 403 forbidden and do not load.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function HomeController($scope) {
    $scope.search = function() {
        $scope.movies = [ 
            { Title: 'The Matrix', Poster: 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU4NTczODkwM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzEyMTIyMw@@._V1._SY317_.jpg' },
            { Title: 'The Matrix Reloaded', Poster: 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg1NTkxOTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwODc4MTc4._V1._SY317_.jpg' }
        ];
    };
}
```

Comment: The titles are wrong :D

Comment: Those posters are for StarWars. Yes, I looked.

Comment: lol, yeah I got lazy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that imdb is checking the referer so other parties are not allowed to embeded their images directly on their website. If you try with images from other domains, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/PZJKZ/2/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function HomeController($scope) {
    $scope.search = function() {
        $scope.movies = [ 
            { Title: 'The Matrix', Poster: 'http://dartr.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/javascript-logo.png' },
            { Title: 'The Matrix Reloaded', Poster: 'http://wpmu.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/jquery-logo1.png' }
        ];
    };
}
```

Comment: Man, that sucks. I guess I have to go with the RottenTomatoes API :(

Comment: Disclaimer: I do not know how the copyright laws etc. works on  these images, so you would have to check that first. But you could pull down the images manually, or have a script download them and host it on your domain.