# Django 403 Forbidden Error on using External image

Tags: python, html, django

I am using Django templates to display thumbnails of movie posters. Here is my view code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def hello(request):
    t = get_template('index.html')
    c = django.template.Context({'test':'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIwNTYzMzE1M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTE5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX300.jpg'})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

In my template, I am trying to use this image to display the thumbnail:

```
<li>
  <img src="{{ test }}" alt="" title="" class="property_img"/>
</li>
```

I am getting this error:

> GET http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIwNTYzMzE1M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTE5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX300.jpg 403 (Forbidden)

My local static files are working, but what if I want to fetch image from a web server?

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting 403 forbidden when dynamically loading images in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369471/getting-403-forbidden-when-dynamically-loading-images-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by the web server (Apache, Nginx, etc) at `ia.media-imdb.com`.

Their web server will check the HTTP `REFERER` header of every visitor, and only allow access to the image only, if a visitor is coming from certain domains.

That is a common setup to limit the amount of [hotlinking to images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking) (when people link directly to image files on other hosts). Hot-linking is often prevented, because it causes traffic without actually getting a site real visitors.

A solution would be to link images from a different site, that does not prevent hotlinking.