# I get a 403 error when inserting an image tag into my website

Tags: html, image, xss, http-status-code-403

I'm dynamically inserting the following tag into my webpage:

`<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTgxMDczMTA5N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzk1MzMzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg">`

When I go to the linked address, the image shows up fine. When I try to load it on my development server at http://localhost:8000, it shows up fine. But when I try to load it on my production server at http://example.org, it doesn't show up, and the console shows "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Here's the javascript that inserts the tag:

`$("#sb-photo").html('<img src="' + movie.Poster + '">');`

UPDATE: This older question seems to address the same problem:

[Getting 403 forbidden when dynamically loading images in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369471/getting-403-forbidden-when-dynamically-loading-images-in-angularjs)

However, the accepted answer doesn't actually work, at least not anymore.

Also, I just realized that the first time I insert an image, it works. But following times I get the 403 error.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369471/getting-403-forbidden-when-dynamically-loading-images-in-angularjs

Comment: You might not be able to get around this issue, especially if the place where you're calling the images doesn't let methods such as yours pull them into another website. I've seen a few sites that prevent this action from happening to avoid content theft.