# Special character in img src (@)

Tags: html, image, character

I'm populating a page with images. Each one comes from an external url (imdb). But there is a set of images that are not loading, appearing as a broken link. All url's of such images include an '@':

`<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjQyODg5Njc4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzExMjE3NzE@._V1_SX300.jpg" class="sf-img" style="opacity: 1;">`

Oddly enough, when testing it locally (localhost) the images load without issue. But when I upload it to my server and test it, then the images appear as missing.

I'm kinda lost here. I'm not sure if the '@' is causing this or not.

The rest of the images load correctly.

Comment: Have a read about url encoding. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp.

Comment: Alredy tried with encodeURI() with no luck. '@' is part of the reserved characters

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: The real problem was with the permissions from the requested server. I got 403 response when trying to include the image from within my page from my server. Its apparently a security measure from IMDB.
I got to the solution for this following these past questions:

[I get a 403 error when inserting an image tag into my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231735/i-get-a-403-error-when-inserting-an-image-tag-into-my-website)

[Getting 403 forbidden when dynamically loading images in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369471/getting-403-forbidden-when-dynamically-loading-images-in-angularjs)